# Store date-time data as numbers

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

The current project I’m working on uses an Oracle DBMS to store data.  During development I found that Date information is not stored in a Date field, but in a VARCHAR2 column with some weird formatting. For example, look at this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "A_TABLE"
  (    
    "OSERC_FEC_INICIO_OS"            VARCHAR2(14 BYTE),
    "OSERC_FEC_FIN_OS"               VARCHAR2(14 BYTE),
    "OSERC_FEC_REGISTRO_PETICION"    VARCHAR2(14 BYTE),
    "OSERC_FEC_APROBACION_PETICION"  VARCHAR2(14 BYTE),
    "OSERC_FEC_LIQUIDACION_OS"       VARCHAR2(14 BYTE),
    "OSERC_FEC_EJECUCION_OS"         VARCHAR2(14 BYTE),
)
```

The fields `OSERC_FEC_REGISTRO_PETICION, OSERC_FEC_APROBACION_PETICION, OSERC_FEC_LIQUIDACION_OS` and `OSERC_FEC_EJECUCION_OS` stores date information but are declared as VARCHAR2 columns. If you check the data, you’ll see that they use the format `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` to store that information.

I’m concerned because I need to build queries that uses this dates in the WHERE clause, and I’m not sure what will be the index performance with that approach. So, what are the problems involved in the design I mentioned? It would be better is the date fields where NUMBER instead of VARCHAR2?

Comment: No it would be better if they were dates.

Comment: Don't explicitly quote columns when creating tables / views etc. It causes more problems than it's worth. If you don't quote them then everything is assumed to be uppercase (however you type it) and there's no need for you to do anything. It also saves a lot of typing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be much better if the dates were stored as dates.  Storing them as numbers rather than strings introduces a different set of problems.

If you are absolutely stuck with dates stored as strings, in order to allow indexes on the columns to be used, you'd need to convert the dates you're using as parameters as strings in the appropriate format and then rely on the fact that sorting of strings in that particular format matches the expected sort order of actual dates.  If you ever compare the string to date or to a number, you're going to get implicit data type conversion which, at best, will lead to performance problems because indexes cannot be used and at worst will generate incorrect results or errors.

Assuming you avoid data type conversion, the performance issues are likely to arise from the fact that the optimizer has a great deal of difficulty estimating cardinality when you use the wrong data type.  Oracle knows, for example, that there are 365 days (or 8760 hours or 525600 minutes) between 1/1/2012 and 1/1/2013.  On the other hand, there are billions of possible strings between '20120101000000' and '20130101000000'.  That can cause the optimizer not to use an index when you would like it to (or vice versa), to use the wrong sort of join, etc.

Comment: Nice I would never have considered the cardinality estimation.

Comment: Besides cardinality, is there other issue using a NUMBER field to store a date? I've read a couple of articles a long time ago that recommended that approach

Comment: @CarlosGavidia - No more than storing dates as strings assuming that you never have years before 1000 (since that would cause the leading 0 of the date to get truncated).  You have the same data type conversion and cardinality problems that you do with strings.  The operations to deal with components of the date either require converting to a string or using less-than-obvious mathematical operations (i.e. `trunc(dt/10000)*10000` to truncate the date to hour).

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is better if they are stored as dates.  You can convert them using:

```
to_char(<field>, <format string>)
```

And I think the format string 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS' works, but I'm not positive.

However, there might be a reason why they chose this format.  Oracle stores date/times as a numbers.  Extracting year, month, day, hour minutes, and seconds requires a bit of mathematical manipulation.  Depending on the processing environment, it might be much easier to use substring operations to extract date components.

My guess is that if the code is using these fields, then there are multiple examples where string operations are being used.  This seems like an intentional design decision, so check things out carefully before changing it (to what is a better solution).