# Unable to call stored procedure in oracle through JDBC

Tags: jdbc, oracle10g

I am trying to call a stored procedure where i am inserting 7 values into a table. But the below code is not working, please tell what am i doing wrong ?

i do not get any error, the page just remains static though after successful query execution it is suppose to redirect to a new page.

```
   public class admincontrol extends TagSupport
 {

HttpServletRequest request;
HttpServletResponse response;
String msg="";

public int doStartTag() throws JspException
 {
       request=(HttpServletRequest)pageContext.getRequest();
       response=(HttpServletResponse)pageContext.getResponse();
       return EVAL_PAGE;
    }
     public void check ()
     {
       JspWriter out=pageContext.getOut(); 
        Connection con;
       CallableStatement stmt;
       ResultSet rs;
    try
   {
       try
        {
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         }
          catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
       {
          out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }


          HttpSession mysession=request.getSession();
          String sess=(String)mysession.getAttribute("user");

       String  rr=(String)adminmodel.time.trim();
       String tempid=(String)adminmodel.employeid.trim();
       String tdept=(String)adminmodel.department.trim();
       String tsup=(String)adminmodel.supervisor.trim();
       String tact=(String)adminmodel.action.trim();
       String tdate=(String)adminmodel.date.trim();


       HttpSession session1=request.getSession();
       session1.setAttribute("requestnum",rr);

     Random rand = new Random(); 
     int r= rand.nextInt(80001) + 19999;
     String reff = String.valueOf(r); 

    if (!tempid.matches(".*[%#^<>&;'\0-].*") && !tdept.matches(".*

     [%#^<>&;'\0-].*") && !tsup.matches(".*[%#^<>&;'\0-].*"))
  {

   if (tempid.equals(sess) )
  {
  if (adminmodel.department!="" && adminmodel.supervisor!="" && adminmodel.action!="" && adminmodel.date!="" && adminmodel.time!="")
  {
     try
  {
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","gaurav","oracle");
 stmt=con.prepareCall("begin requestdetail (?,?,?,?,?,?,?); end;");
    stmt.setString(1,tempid);
    stmt.setString(2,tsup);
    stmt.setString(3,tdept);  
    stmt.setString(4,tact);  
    stmt.setString(5,tdate);  
    stmt.setString(6,rr);
    stmt.setString(7,reff);           
    rs=stmt.executeQuery();
   response.sendRedirect("requestnum.jsp");    
  }
   catch(SQLException ex)
  {
    out.println(ex.getMessage());
  }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
    out.println(ex.getMessage());
   }
 }
    else 
    out.println("Enter complete details"); 
  }
    else 
    out.println("Incorrect Employee Id"); 
  }
    else
    out.println("Invalid Details "); 
 }

   catch(Exception ex)
 {

  } 
 }

  public int doEndTag() throws JspException
{

  check();
  return super.doEndTag();
 }

}
```

Below is the stored procedure

```
create or replace procedure requestdetail (id number, sup varchar2, department       varchar2,aaction varchar2, adate number,atime number, ref number)
is
begin
insert into myadmin(employe_id,supervisor,department,action,sdate,stime,reference_no)values (id,sup,department,aaction,adate,atime, ref);
end;
/
```

Comment: 'Not working' is not a valid or useful error message. Please always say what error(s) or unexpected behaviour you get, and what you expect to happen. I'm assuming you get something like 'wrong number or type of arguments', or 'invalid identifier', from the call itself. Your procedure may be invalid as well, potentially; is the first column really called `employe_id`, rather than `employee_id`? If it 'compiled with warnings' then do `show errors` or `select * from user_errors` to see what was wrong.

Comment: I have updated the entire code, please take a look. I do not get any error, the page just remains static, tried using  stmt=con.prepareCall("{ call requestdetail (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) }"); and stmt=con.prepareCall("begin; requestdetail (?,?,?,?,?,?,?); end;"); nothing works

Comment: What happens to `msg`? If you aren't getting the redirect you expect, it seems possible you're getting an exception somewhere. Does `tempid` actually match `sess` - sounds like they'd be different on an admin page, but not sure what this is doing. This seems like a JSP debug issue, though the DB call you have now is wrong...

Comment: thats what the issue is neither the query is executed nor getting any exception.  i am making sure before submitting all the conditions are met but still no luck.

Comment: How do you know you aren't getting an exception - how is `check` called, and what do you do with the returned `msg` value; is it displayed or logged somewhere? What debugging are you doing to see what's happening inside the method?

Comment: the code that i have updated is giving the error " ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error ORA-06512: at line 1" can you tell me what could be reason ?
In oracle i have created all columns of varchar2

Comment: The definition of your `requestdetail` procedure is expecting numbers. I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a procedure in a query, only a function. To execute a procedure you need to do:

```
stmt=con.prepareCall("{ call requestdetail (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) }");
stmt.setString(1,tempid);
stmt.setString(2,tsup);
stmt.setString(3,tdept);  
stmt.setString(4,tact);  
stmt.setString(5,tdate);  
stmt.setString(6,rr);
stmt.setString(7,reff);           
rs=stmt.execute();
```

Or if you prefer you can pass a PL/SQL block:

```
stmt=con.prepareCall("begin; requestdetail (?,?,?,?,?,?,?); end;");
```

You will also need to `commit` at some point, unless you have auto commit turned on for the connection.

Also, you're setting all the parameters using `setString`, and you said in a comment that the table was created with all `varchar2` columns; but your procedure is expecting numbers for the `id`, `adate` and `atime` columns:

```
create or replace procedure requestdetail (id number, sup varchar2,
  department varchar2, aaction varchar2, adate number, atime number,
  ref number) is
```

That will get a `numeric or value error` if the values you pass in for `tempid`, `tdate` and `rr` are not actually numbers. It looks like you're expecting `tempid` at least to be a string.

But if they are numeric (or, as the name suggests, date) values then your table columns should be of the appropriate type anyway, not all `varchar2`. Always use the correct data type; don't try to store numbers or dates as strings, it will only cause you pain later. It affects performance as Oracle can't optimise execution plans and indexes based on the actual data type. But more importantly because you can get invalid or just bad data, which you might not notice until much later, and will struggle to correct.

If someone inserts a string into your 'number' field nothing will stop them; but at some point when you query with `where adate = 1` it'll throw an error. Same with dates, but even worse depending on the format(s) used - even with a single format, if you think everything is DD/MM/YYYY and someone puts in a value by mistake as MM/DD/YYYY, again you won't know; and it'll either work when retrieved (if the DD and MM are both <= 12) but have the wrong value and you will have no way to tell; or it'll fail when retrieved. If the column was `DATE` then it's up to the person inserting to get it right, not up to you to try and fix mistakes when you retrieve the data.

Comment: Thanks.. could you also tell me why is it wrong not to store number as a string in the database ?

Comment: @user3337264 - updated with some background. [See this as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10725075/266304).